# How can I add two or more elements to a list from a single input in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

What my script is doing now is adding elements to a list. For example, if the user types "JO", I will add "John" to the list. What I want to do now is that, if the user types "2 JO", I add two elements to the list: "John" and "John".
This is how the database looks like now:

[Sample database copy.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsBSU.png)

This is the code now:

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_excel("Sample database copy.xlsx")
name = dict(zip(data["Abbreviation"],data["Name"]))
list1 = []
incoming_msg = input(Please type what you want to add: )
list1.append(name[incoming_msg])
```

I need to do it all from the same input, I cannot ask separately for quantity and abbreviation. I wanted to know if there is any library that can do this somehow easily because I am a beginner coder. If there is no library but you have any idea how I could solve it, it would be awesome as well.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: the module you use to look for patterns and parse strings is re (regular expressions). in this case you don't need regular expressions because the pattern is simple, but for more complex patterns regular expressions is a great tool that makes your life easier.

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking the time to answer. Do you have any example on how I could use it? I started coding a few weeks ago and all I am reading is chinese 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use string.split() to split the string by space into a list then use the first element to multiply a list that contains the value from the dictionary and increment it to the result list. see the code

```
name = dict(zip(data["Abbreviation"],data["Name"]))
list1 = []
incoming_msg = input('Please type what you want to add: ')
incoming_msg = incoming_msg.split() # split the string by space
if len(incoming_msg) == 2: # if there are two elements in the list (number and name)
    list1 += [name[incoming_msg[1]]] * int(incoming_msg[0])
else:
    list1.append(name[incoming_msg[0]])
```

Comment: How could I do the same but for removing the objects? I am trying with the operator -= but it is not working.